# kendo ui grid edit/navigation

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there such as thing as "edit mode" versus "navigation mode" on the kendo UI grid? Normally the expected behavior is that once editing of a certain cell begins, navigation (such as up and down arrow keys etc.) is disabled and all such key actions are received by the editing component.

I'm using a custom component to do the editing (content editable div) of the cell and I'm wondering if there is anything that i need to do to disable navigation while editing is happening.